# If a living being is not self aware than can he experience suffering or pleasure?

Tags: awareness

When some living being like dog or any mini bacteria are killed, since they are not self aware or concious do they feel the same type of pain as we do? what is the difference between their suffering and our suffering?

Comment: What do you mean by self-aware? Being conscious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dogs don't forget pain. You only have to look at a dog that has been continuously beaten and then cringes or tries to bite anyone who tries to pet it.  Yes it has become an automatic reaction but there must be some kind of memory there about humans not being trustworthy.

Answer (score 1):

Its very clear that dogs are conscious  and feel the same pain as humans do and the suffering is the same suffering

If by self aware you mean mindful- than most people arent mindful 99.9999% of the time     ---  many many monks if good ones are not mindful most of the time

About bacteria i cant say much

Answer (score 0):

I think that (according to Buddhism) humans, animals, ghosts, and residents of hell all belong to the same kind of category: all "[sentient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentient_beings_(Buddhism))", all composed of the five skandhas, and all subject to suffering.

Since all belong to the same continuum (i.e. samsara), I expect that they all "lose memory" and that their "suffering finishes" in much the same way.

I don't consider a dog as like a bacterium, by the way: IMO a bacterium is more like a plant than an animal. I think different schools of Buddhism differ on whether plants are "sentient" and have any "consciousness".

**don't they just forget or loose the momory of their suffering after it is finished?**

Isn't that more-or-less true (or untrue) of people too?

Answer (score -1):

It is hard to say unless you are an animal or bacteria.
In general observation, it appears animals such as dogs enjoy the sex and they feel the pain.
According to Buddhist teaching animals possess five aggregate same as the human.

Interesting video to watch. In this video, it is explained in plain English that any living and breathing organism has consciousness and how we interpret pain and pleasure.

[Your brain hallucinates your conscious reality | Anil Seth](https://youtu.be/lyu7v7nWzfo)

Answer (score -1):

More primitive life forms, such as worms or fish, have a nervous system, therefore their nervous system experiences physical pain. Dogs are probably more complex and have emotions such as lust, love, *emotional* attachment; that makes them experience *emotional* sorrow & unhappiness.

However. as we can directly experience, homo sapiens (people) have the *egoistic* attachment (*upadana*) of self-identity (*sakkaya ditthi*), which is born from thought conception. This *upadana* of *sakkaya ditthi* is the '*suffering*' ('*dukkha*') Buddhism seeks to eliminate.

I think it is a fair assumption worms & fish cannot create the *upadana* of *sakkaya ditthi*; and probably also dogs.

> *Bhikkhu, ‘**I am**’ **is a conceiving**; ‘**I am** this’ is a conceiving; ‘**I** shall be’ is a conceiving; ‘**I** shall not be’ is a conceiving; ‘**I** shall
>   be possessed of form’ is a conceiving; ‘**I** shall be formless’ is a
>   conceiving; ‘**I** shall be percipient’ is a conceiving; ‘**I** shall be
>   non-percipient’ is a conceiving; ‘**I** shall be
>   neither-percipient-nor-non-percipient’ is a conceiving. **Conceiving is
>   a disease, conceiving is a tumour, conceiving is a dart**. By overcoming
>   all conceivings, bhikkhu, one is called a sage at peace. MN 140*

Answer (score -1):

In all [31 planes of existence](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sagga/loka.html) there is attachment to life except for the plane for [Unconscious Beings (asaññasatta)](https://suttacentral.net/define/asa%C3%B1%C3%B1asatt%C4%81). So a dog feels pain thus like us.

Also any being in any plane are self aware except for enlightened beings who do not have self conceiving.

Also we all lose some notion of suffering otherwise hence why 1st Noble Truth is not readily comprehensible.